# Regular expression to ignore the numbers after length reaches 10

Tags: javascript, regex

I want number in this format

(123)-456-7890

The maximum length assigned is 10.

The regular expression used to obtain the above format is:

```
if (onlyNums.length === 10) {
            const number = onlyNums.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) -$2-$3');
```

If length>10 I want the above format for the number and to ignore the rest of the digits(right trim).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the `if` condition and add a "catch-all" regex `.*` at the end, it will ignore whatever comes after the 10th digit:

```
const number = onlyNums.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '($1) -$2-$3');
```

This assumes that `onlyNums` actually contains nothing but digits (and at least 10 of them). Otherwise, the result might be unexpected.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UyFanr/1).